# Keycloak version 21 how to fix the CORS origin issue in keycloak

Tags: cors, token, keycloak-connect

last one week i tried Single sign on authentication (SSO)
Front end is angular technologies.
( common keycloak-URL and common realm-name, client name only different ).
keycloak version 21.1.0 , but I am always getting CORS issue ( realms/realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/token ).

keycloakconfig.json

{
"url": "https://keycloak.ipaddress",
"realm": "realm-name",
"clientId": "demo-testing",
"ssl-required": "external",
"verify-token-audience": true,
"credentials": {
"secret": ""
},
"onLoad": "login-required",
"checkLoginIframe": true,
"checkLoginIframeInterval": 25,
"loadUserProfileAtStartUp": true
}

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The way I solved it was by going to the Keycloak **Client**, go to Web Origin and paste either `*` or your `url`

[image]

Comment: Keycloak version 21 changed the url from /auth to /admin, once changed my redirect problem resolved.